# Angular Project not working after git clone

Tags: angular, git, clone

I'm trying to clone my project to the latest working version, after a simple **git reset --hard** .

The project itself is an Angular Project.

After i clone it and reset it, i run the **npm install** and then the classic **ng serve**.

But after compilation, it gives me some errors

```
 Error: node_modules/@angular/material/chips/chip.d.ts:120:9 - error TS2611: 'disabled' is defined as 
 a property in class 'CanColor & CanDisableRipple & HasTabIndex & MatChipBase', but is overridden here in 
 'MatChip' as an accessor.

 120     get disabled(): boolean;
        ~~~~~~~~


   Error: node_modules/@angular/material/radio/radio.d.ts:184:9 - error TS2611: 'disabled' is defined as a property in class 'CanDisableRipple & HasTabIndex & MatRadioButtonBase', but is overridden here in '_MatRadioButtonBase' as an accessor.

   184     get disabled(): boolean;
        ~~~~~~~~


   Error: node_modules/@angular/material/table/cell.d.ts:42:5 - error TS2610: 'name' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkColumnDef', but is overridden here in 'MatColumnDef' as an instance property.

   42     name: string;
   ~~~~


 Error: node_modules/@angular/material/tree/padding.d.ts:15:5 - error TS2610: 'level' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkTreeNodePadding<T>', but is overridden here in 'MatTreeNodePadding<T>' as an instance property.

 15     level: number;
   ~~~~~


 Error: node_modules/@angular/material/tree/padding.d.ts:17:5 - error TS2610: 'indent' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkTreeNodePadding<T>', but is overridden here in 'MatTreeNodePadding<T>' as an instance property.

 17     indent: number;
   ~~~~~~


 Error: node_modules/@angular/material/tree/toggle.d.ts:14:5 - error TS2610: 'recursive' is defined as an accessor in class 'CdkTreeNodeToggle<T>', but is overridden here in 'MatTreeNodeToggle<T>' as an instance property.

 14     recursive: boolean;
   ~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Perhaps delete your node_modules folder and then make an `npm install` again

Comment: @Guldborg92 I already tried with npm install. I run that command right after the clone

Comment: All right. The reason to delete the node_modules folder was because I just figured your node_modules on your repo or locally were out-of-sync :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your version of Angular match your version of Angular Material